# Proving Cauchy-Riemann equations for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-riemann-equations

[image]

Need a little help guys, can someone help me on this? I am unable to think about how to prove this. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The question says 'show that', so just substitute the CR definitions into the equations.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)